# Method Illuminate\Http\Request::setTrustedHeaderName does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

After upgrading to laravel 5.6.21 from 5.5.28 i get this error:

> Method Illuminate\Http\Request::setTrustedHeaderName does not exist.

further info from log:

> laravel.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::setTrustedHeaderName
>   does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code:
>   0): Method Illuminate\Http\Request::setTrustedHeaderName does not
>   exist. at
>   /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:99)

[stacktrace]

```
#0 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(140): Illuminate\\Http\\Request->__call('setTrustedHeade...', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(53): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->setTrustedProxyHeaderNames(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#2 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#3 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#4 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(51): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#18 /home/vagrant/slf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /home/vagrant/slf/public_html/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 {main}
```

any help would be great

Comment: run composer update

Comment: that isn't the full solution to the problem, i have however figured it out. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to fix it is changing

```
"fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
```

To

```
"fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
```

In the `composer.json` file, ran `$composer update` and then in the `TrustProxies.php` file located at:

```
App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies
```

I changed the protected headers from:

```
protected $headers = [
    Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
];
```

To

```
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

Comment: Those two first parts about `composer.json` are exactly the same.